# When to decide to use typedef's data types or C's built-in standard data types

Tags: c, typedef

gcc 4.7.2
c89

Hello,

I am using the Apache Portable Runtime and looking at their typedef's

```
typedef short apr_int16_t
typedef int apr_int16_t
typedef size_t apr_size_t /* This is basically the same, so what's the point */
```

etc.

1. So what is the point of all this?
2. When should you decided to use C's built-in standard data types or typedef's data types?

I just gave a example using the APR. However, I am also speaking generally as well. There is also the stdint.h header file that typedef's data types.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: The point is to protect the APR from gratuitous changes imposed from outside. However, this would be better on programmers.

Comment: Also, if say short is now some how different and the same short has become "byte" , then you can change this one location to make all other files that uses "arp_int16_t" become byte

Comment: I don't know much about the APR, but they may not be using `int16_t` and family from `inttypes.h` because some implementations don't support C99, like Microsoft's compiler. Using `apr_int16_t` instead allows them to work around issues like these, albeit it's kind of a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.

1. So what is the point of all this?

   It's meant to be for abstraction, but like anything else, it is sometimes misused/overused.
   Sometimes it's necessary for backwards compatibility (e.g. `typedef VOID void` in Windows), sometimes it's necessary for proper abstraction (e.g. `typedef unsigned int size_t`), and sometimes it's completely pointless logically, but makes typing easier (e.g. `typedef char const *LPCSTR` in Windows).
2. When should you decided to use C's built-in standard data types or typedef's data types?

   If it makes something easier, or if it implements a proper abstraction barrier, use it.
   What exactly that means is something you'll just have to learn over time.
   But don't use it "just for kicks"!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it is better to have custom defined data types for native data types of the system as it helps in clearly distingushing the size of the types.

For Ex: A long may be 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the machine in which your code runs and the way it has been built. But, if your code specifically needs a 64 bit variable, then naming it as uint_64_t or something similar will always help in associating the size clearly.

In such cases, the code be written as:

```
    #if _64BIT_
    typedef long uint_64_t
    #else
    typedef long long uint_64_t
    #endif
```

But as suggested by Mehrdad, don't use it "just for kicks". : )